# android best way to write and read lots of arrays?

Tags: android, arrays

I've been looking at this http://blog.javia.org/assembly-java/ and in particular this bit #6: `Don’t use String. Use char array instead.`
Does anyone have an example of storing and retrieving data in this way?

For example I have arrays like this

```
int[] myInts = new int[256];
int[] myotherInts = new int[256];
byte[] mybytes = new byte[someLength];
```

Comment: There's a bunch of examples of this kind of character manipulation **[here.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ExtractingasubstringasanarrayofcharactersusingthemethodgetChars.htm)**

Comment: @Zeke wtf do you think you are doing editing my post? big thanks to everyone else :)

Comment: @user1033558: I'd strongly recommend you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially:

```
String text = "To be or not to be";

char[] textArray = new char[3];
text.getChars(9, 12, textArray, 0);
```

So all of your strings are stored in a single array, and then extracted separately using `getChars()`.